# I can't see react lint errors in my browser console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, eslint

I started a new ReactJS project, using `npx create-react-app` and I can't see lint errors in browser, but they are shown on vscode terminal. I really don't know what to do, I want the another way around, to be shown on browser console, and maybe not in terminal. I tried with different browsers, with the same outcome. This is the `package.json` file that it's used.

```
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.17.3",
    "i18next": "^21.6.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.15.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Terminal messages you see happen during the build, you are comparing that with javascript's console which is run-time I think.

Comment: Lint doesn't run in the browser so it's not clear how it would show linting warnings. Any particular reason you want this requirement? Surely it would be much better to see them in the IDE so you can correct them as you type?

Comment: It's easier for me to see them in browser console, and yes, I'm talking about the run-time errors. I have in terminal run-time errors/warnings too, about those I'm talking

Comment: I can't say that is impossible, but linting as static code analysis tool typically is useful for the developer when writing code. Therefore normally it is either part of a build process - the lint warnings and errors appearing in your terminal where the build process runs - or when code is written e.g. integreatedi n the IDE.

Comment: I'm not talking about fairy tales, but every react project until this one had lint errors on browser console

Comment: Never worked that way with linting and never used create-react-app template. I stand corrected after reading create-react-app docs: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#displaying-lint-output-in-the-editor.

Answer (score -1):

It never happened with me, but try to stop your application, delete the node_modules folder and run `npm i` again to install all the dependencies.

Comment: I already did this